# Finding Common and uncommon values in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have some values/numbers from A2 thru F8, I need the common values in 1 column (i.e the values which are common in A,B,C,D,E & F)-THIS CAN BE IN COLUMN H

I also need values uncommon only in A, only in B, only in C...F.

I need values andnot True/False.

```
                     Common within A,B,C,D,E,F      uncommon only in A,B,C,D,E,F                
A   B   C   D   E   F                                  |A   B   C   D   E   F
1   2   5   88  1   1          1                       |?   ?   ?   88  ?   ?
2   6   2   5   2   2          2                       |?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
3   5   15  9   45  9          ?                       |3   ?   15  ?   45  ?
4   7   4   2   8   0          ?                       |4   7   ?   ?   ?   0
99  9   1   1   5   8          ?                       |99  ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
```

Comment: I understand what you need, but not what the question is... Do you want us to just do this for you? What have you tried? Let's see your efforts and then we can help you out based upon what you show

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: What common means for you? E.g. in you example there is 1 as common, but it isn't present in column B. Is it necessary for common column to be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

In **G1** enter:

**=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$F$10,A1)=5,A1,"")**

and copy down:

[image]

This technique will only work if there are no duplicates within a single column.

Comment: This works well, i earlier tried but some how i was making mistake in the formula =IF(COUNTIF($B$6:$I$505,B6)=8,B6,"false"). i have now rectified the mistake.